# How are $Q-\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ isomorphic as linear orders?

Tags: order-theory

Exercise 2.3 of Linear Orderings by Joseph G. Rosenstein asks to show that the linear orders are isomorphic. But if $f$ is an isomorphism from  $Q-\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ then it must be an increasing function on $Q-\{0\}$. Also according to the hint given in the question since $X=\{2^{-n}\vert\hspace{0.1cm} n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ does not have a LUB in $Q-\{0\}$, $\hspace{0.2cm}f(X)$ does not have an LUB in $\mathbb{Q}$ which implies that $f(0)$ tends to infinity. How are these two conditions reconcilable?

Comment: Not having an LUB does not mean it tends to infinity, it just means that the LUB in the sense of the reals is not a member of the set.  Consider the set of rationals less than $\sqrt 2$.  It does not have an LUB in $\Bbb Q$, but it does have an upper bound.

Comment: What is $Q$? Is it a typo and means $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh, I see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PaulFrost The author used these notations. I thought that the author considered $\mathbb{Q}$ as a linear order and $Q$ as just the underlying set.